# Moving in 3D world - OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, camera, rotation

So I am currently working on some game elements including some engine-like stuff in OpenGL and I have come to this problem. (dealing with 3D world)
I am getting the angles of rotation in the world by mouse, like this:

```
int prevX = mouse.x;
int prevY = mouse.y;

GetCursorPos(&mouse);

cam.xRot -= atan(prevX-mouse.x);
cam.yRot -= atan(prevY-mouse.y);
```

Seems working good. (the xRot is in fact meant like rotation around Y axis and yRot around x axis)
Camera rotation is good. Then I started to work on movement relative to the camera. After some drawings and desperate attempts I came to this:

```
//W
if (keys[57])
       {
           cam.z += cos(angleY)*cos(angleX)*cam.speed;
           cam.x -= cos(angleY)*sin(angleX)*cam.speed;
           cam.y += sin(angleY);
       }
//S
if (keys[53])
       {
          cam.z -= cos(angleY)*cos(angleX)*cam.speed;
          cam.x += cos(angleY)*sin(angleX)*cam.speed;
          cam.y -= sin(angleY);
       }
//A
if (keys[41])
       {
          cam.z += sin(angleX)*cam.speed;
          cam.x += cos(angleX)*cam.speed;
       }
//D
if (keys[44])
       {
          cam.z -= cos(angleY)*sin(angleX)*cam.speed;
          cam.x -= cos(angleY)*cos(angleX)*cam.speed;
       }
```

It works too but the problem is when I rotate the camera around z axis (the depth one). I tried some combinations etc but nothing seems to be working. What am I missing?
I made the equations above like this:
When I take it as a 2D just x and z and I want to go forward with camera rotated by zero angle I need to move only in the z axis direction, in a positive way so let's use a function with it's maximum there => cos. When I rotate by 90 and need to move forward I need to move on x axis so let's use sin cause we need the opposite. That handle's 2D well. 
Now I needed to add z axis so I though that maybe just restrict the values of x and y by cos of the second angle (yRot or angle of rotation around x if you want) and make sin of it the actual movement on y axis.
Yea working good but as I said problems when I rotate around z and basically switch the y and x axis.
What to do with it? :D

Oh by the way I have read some other tutorials and I noticed that some people use a different ways with vectors etc. What is a common way in today's games? I don't really like using goniometric functions so often. Maybe my approach is not the best one huh?

Comment: For movement it is definitely better to use vectors. Removes all the trig functions, making your code more efficient. For camera rotation look up the LookAt algorithms. Then for movement look up translation matrices. The idea would be to build the rotation matrix from the LookAt, then build the translation matrix based on the previous position and the speed. Multiply the two matrices to generate the objects new world matrix.

Comment: mm thanks, I will take a look at it, I guess it will improve the performance at least if I don't use too much of math.h :D

Comment: will vector math usually just involves subtraction and additions. Sin and Cos involve division. It's a matter of 1 clock cycle vs 9-27 clock cycles.

Comment: yea you're probably right

Comment: Trigonometry is familiar to many with a high school education, which is probably why programmers try it first.  But compared to vectors and dot products and cross products, trig is *very slow* and has some painful edge cases.  Trig also forces you to pretend that every 3D math problem is really a 2D math problem.

Comment: Thinking about it, don't you still need sin and cos for the basic rotations? Like when you have the rotation matrix there are cos and sin needed not?

Comment: Yes, you do need them for the rotation matrix. That is why it isn't recommended to use them in the translation as well.

Comment: One more question, how to build the translation matrix relatively to the rotation? I mean that's the main problem for me, how to do that without trigonometry? Tell me at lest the principle or where to find it please. ^^"

Comment: Hmm maybe I can use the mouse coordinates as a vector instead of converting them to angle. But still not sure how to get the translation matrix of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to camera management, most people seem to make it far more difficult than it had to be. The key point is matrix math.

Consider an object with world matrix `W`, which consists of a rotation and a translation part. If we want to move this object to its right, we can just multiply an according translation matrix to `W` (note that all further explanations assume the OpenGL notation with column vectors and column-major matrices):

```
W* = W * T(x, 0, 0)
```

The important thing is the multiplication order. If you multiply the translation matrix to the right side, it will move the object in the object's local coordinate system. If you multiply it to the left side, it will move it in the global coordinate system. Similarly, we can multiply a rotation matrix to rotate the object in its local coordinate system:

```
W** = W* * Rx(phi)
```

Now, the view matrix of camera's is a bit trickier because it is actually an inverted matrix. So if you have a view matrix `V`, you have to multiply the inverse matrices to the left side:

```
V*  = T(-x, 0, 0) * V
V** = Rx(-phi) * V*
//...
```

One problem of this, though, is the fixture of the up-vector. If you perform rotations about the local y axis, the up-direction might get changed. We could calculate an adapted matrix, which avoids this, but just re-calculating the entire rotation matrix from the two angles is probably much easier. After re-calculating the matrix, you must re-position it at the old position (global position, so multiply a translation matrix to the left). Calculating the old position requires a bit of math (because the matrix is inverted):

```
pos = -tx * first row - ty * second row - tz * third row
where tx is the entry in the first row, last column
      ty is the entry in the second row, last column
      tz is the entry in the third row, last column
```

### Summary

If you want to maintain a flexible camera representation, store the view matrix and the two rotation angles. If you want to move the camera, just multiply a translation matrix. If you want to rotate the camera about the local x-axis, change the angle and multiply the rotation matrix. If you want to rotate about the local y-axis, change the angle and re-calculate the entire matrix, including a repositioning.

Your current solution basically does this because the trigonometric results are exactly the entries of the matrix at the relevant positions. But as you see, it is quite cumbersome to maintain and if you want to allow a third rotation, you would have to change the entire code.

Embrace matrix maths!

Comment: Thanks, so how to use it in term of OpenGL? I am still a bit confused, when I multiply rotation and translation matrix and then draw the objects it still doesn't solve the relative movement. Not talking about the last part now, just dealing with rotation of camera around y and walking that direction.

Comment: Somehow I was under the impression that this was an XNA question. Anyway, I changed it to OpenGL. Does that resolve the "relative movement"?

Comment: I understand how I can change the global/local by simply switching the transformation matrices order when multiplying but when I use global I can rotate the world properly, just the translation is still not relative. I am missing something there.
I have the rotation matrix and when multiplied with translation one it's still moving according to the original axis no matter how I rotate.
Sorry for bothering, my head somehow still can't take it :D

Comment: If the translation is not local, then you're just multiplying the matrix at the wrong side. For view matrices, you should always multiply to the left sides (the inverted translation matrices).

Comment: Mmmm I get the rotation matrix with the angle I get from mouse, that's ok, the rotation alone works fine when I try.
But how is the translation supposed to look like? To make it relative? Is it enough to multiply the rot one and transl one where the translation is for example saying: "move on Z by 50.0"? When I do this it moves according to the original Z not the "rotated one".

Comment: A movement along the z-axis would then be a movement along the camera's view direction. Be sure that the order is `T * R`. Then the camera has no choice but move along its view direction.

Comment: I feel like crazy now :D. I changed the order and now when I move mouse the object is rotating and when I press W I can zoom it. That's the first option you talked of right? And when I change the order again to T*R I get that good rotation but bad translation again.
I use a simple matrix multiplication algorithm which is working good so I don't get what's wrong here.

Comment: Then you're probably not acting on the actual view matrix but the camera's model matrix. Is your question solved with that?

Comment: The matrices are not separated in OpenGL no?
I thought that it depends on when I use it whether it's view or model one.

Comment: Can we continue this discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82010/moving-in-3d-world-opengl)?

Comment: Tells me I don't have the reputation. Sorry ^_^"
Well now I tried doing that manually like create the float arrays, multiply as matrices and load it.
It's the same as when I use
glRotatef(curCam->xRot,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
glTranslatef(curCam->x,curCam->y,curCam->z);
though

Comment: It seems you did not get my point completely. One problem is that the legacy matrix stack does not support multiplications to the left side of the current matrix, which is what you would need. But you can emulate this by storing the current matrix in a variable, loading the new matrix and multiply the stored one. Quite ugly and I would really recommend to use a more flexible matrix library for modern OpenGL like glm. Anyway, what I meant is to multiply only the *changes*. If you move the camera, multiply that move matrix. If you rotate, multiply the rotation matrix. Otherwise, do nothing.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I need to experiment with it more and re-read your advices a few times :D.
I was trying to get the current matrix by glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX... then multiply it manually with the rotation one and translation one and then load in back.